# stripe-react-native java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot locate windowRecomposer

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments

In my React Native app I am using @stripe/stripe-react-native library. Recently, I upgraded library to 0.33.0 from 0.22.1.
When I'm opening view containing `CardField` the app (only Android) crashes with such log:

```
unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
unknown:ReactNative: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot locate windowRecomposer; 
View androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView{ [...] app:id/icon} is not attached to a window
```

Is anyone facing this issue?

Comment: 1. Can you provide the code for the view containing the`CardField`?  
2. That's a pretty big version jump have you checked the ChangeLog (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for any breaking changes?